# get mouse postion returns wrong xy

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers

I have an Open-layers map, and I want to add a marker with a mouse over event that displays a pop up. my code is doing this however the pop-up is displayed not on top of the icon that is "mouse overed".

Instead the popup is displayed at the far side of the screen and moves the map slightly. I have added a mouse move function that tell me where the cursor is on the screen and the mouse move event is giving the correct coordinates but the mouseover is giving me values that are almost zero.

I am very new to JavaScript and I completely lost as to what I have got wrong here. any help would be greatly appreciated

here is the javascript

```
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");
//var layer=  new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();

 layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        "Google Hybrid",
        {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, numZoomLevels: 20});
        layer.wrapDateLine=false;
    map.addLayer(layer);
    map.zoomTo(3);

var clat=45.003585;
var clon=6.120495;
var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(clon,clat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));
map.setCenter(lonlat,18); 

markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Cities");               
map.addLayer(markers);  
var location = new OpenLayers.LonLat(6.12053255092622,45.00374430489748).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));            
var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png',size,offset);
marker=new OpenLayers.Marker(location,icon.clone());


map.addControl(
  new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(
  {
        prefix: '<a target="_blank" ' +
          'href="http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/">' +
           'EPSG:4326</a> coordinates: ',
        separator: ' | ',
      numDigits: 2,
     emptyString: 'Mouse is not over map.'

            })
        );
 map.events.register("mousemove", map, function(e) 
 {
     position = this.events.getMousePosition(e);
     OpenLayers.Util.getElement("coords").innerHTML = position;
    lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(position).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));
     OpenLayers.Util.getElement("coords_gps").innerHTML = "lat= " +lonlat.lat +" long= "+lonlat.lon;
 });



//here add mouseover event
marker.events.register('mouseover', marker, function(ev) {
lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(this.events.getMousePosition(ev));
 console.log(this.events.getMousePosition(ev));//.transform(new  OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")));
 popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("Popup",
    lonlat,
    null,
    '<div>Hello World! Put your html here</div>',
    null,
    false);
  map.addPopup(popup);
 });
 //here add mouseout event
  marker.events.register('mouseout', marker, function(evt) {popup.hide();});

markers.addMarker(marker);

 map.events.register("click",map, function (e){
  // alert("here");
     position = this.events.getMousePosition(e);
     lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(position).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));
     $('#lat').val(lonlat.lat);
     $('#lon').val(lonlat.lon);
});
```

Comment: My initial thought is that although you are getting the correct mouse coordinates, there is a mismatch between that and your popup positioning. I'm assuming you're using absolute positioning for the popup. I would hazard a guess that somewhere you are getting coordinates that are relative to the element being hovered over. So although that element might be at pos 200x200 the mouse over it is at pos 4x4 (relative to the 200x200 element) if that makes sense. Can you post the addPopup method? I'm assuming this is creating the wrong positioning

Comment: tommy, thanks for you comment, the popup method is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: but you may be right as the x y vales that are written to the console are about one tenth of what they should be

Comment: I'm not familiar with openlayers, but it looks like the popup actually receives a lon and lat of a position on the map rather than an x,y. You probably just need to add the x,y offset of the map container to your getMousePosition event and then pass those into the getLonLatFromPixel method

Comment: OK I will keep looking, the examples I am following don’t seem to do that, thanks for your comment

Comment: No probs, for what it's worth I was just looking at the openlayer docs. Bear in mind that if your examples have the map in the top left of the page then the examples will work! You said you're new to javascript, so inspect this http://jsfiddle.net/f8wLC/ to see the different properties and what they're relative to by clicking the red box. There's additional properties such as e.clientX and e.target.offsetLeft etc. that might also be of use

Comment: I have got a bit of a work around and I am declaring a global _lonlat variable which assigns a value from the mouse move event. when this is passed in as a value in the mouseovermarker event the whole thing works fine. think I am more confused now than when I started

Comment: Would you mind creating a JSFiddle for this? You could fork an existing one (e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/a8kK4/) and change the code; this would it easier to try and run your example.

Comment: i will look in to doing this, but I haven’t done a jsfiddle before